# Pregnant platies

Tags: fish

I have two platys that look pregnant. I know that they have a square belly and a black spot on their rear end. 
One seems to have been pregnant for ages and just notice signs of the black spot on the other.  How long are they pregnant for? [image]

Comment: I've heard that it's not good to separate the pregnant fish. I've been told to leave her in her own envoirment. I have got a task for her, but was told to leave her be

Comment: Check this post about the same question for more ideas:
http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/9537/how-do-i-care-for-a-pregnant-platy/

Answer (score 4):

Platys are pregnant for about 4 weeks, be sure to add lots of plants for the fry to hide as the parents and other fish will try to eat them.

You can also purchase a [mesh breeder](http://www.petsmart.com/fish/supplies/aquarium-maintenance/breeders/top-fin-aquarium-mesh-breeder-16800.html?cgid=300086) to keep them safe as well.

Comment: The parents will try and eat them? That's pretty abusive.

Comment: Such is life lol, you don't really see it in the wild as the parents leave the area they lay eggs. The fry then have to worry about other predators.